# Firebase Search event Term not showing in analytics

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I report a *Search* event and add the search query to the bundle.
In Firebase, only the event is shown. I can see the stat on the search event log, but I can't see the value of the `Term` that were searched. From what I understand, the `Term` param is supported by Firebase.

Here is my code:

```
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SEARCH_TERM, query);
            mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SEARCH, bundle);
```

What should I do to get the search term to appear in `Firebase?

Comment: is the search term that u send to analytics "query" in your code? If so then send "query" as the key while logging an event. i.e **mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(query, bundle);**, hopefully you can see this on the console page.

Comment: That will create separate event for every search team @Rachana. Not under the FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SEARCH event.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem. Did you get a solution to the problem? Can you currently view the search terms?

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom definitions to solve this problem.

**Here's how**

1. Go to firebase console
2. Then select the custom definition from the left panel
3. click on "create custom dimension" at the top right
4. Then enter the details as shown in this photo

[image]

After entering detail give it some time and then make a search event from your app.

now go to the events tab -> select search event -> and you will see your search term with the count in a separate card.

[More info about the custom dimensions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand from your code in the question, the code does not have any errors.

If you are implementing firebase analytics for the first time, it will take 24 hours for the events to appear in the dashboard.

After first event reported, next events takes around 3-4 hours to update in google dashboard.

Hope this info helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it has been more than a month since I released the app. I can see the event count but not the searched term

Comment: Yes, same here. I made new build and I only see that search event has been triggered 111 times by 5 users. No details. :-/